# How to assign Eth0 IP from external DHCP server to Raspberry Pi4?

Tags: wifi, pi-4, dhcp, ethernet-port

I am trying to assign IP address for Eth0 from my router which has DHCP. I have connected my Pi4 with the router. But the IP is not assigned. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to use Pi4 with Codesys. For that, I am assigning the IP address of the Pi from the DHCP server on the network. But I can't see the IP address of the pi in the terminal using ifconfig. It is assigning some different addresses. So I can't able to scan the device from my PC. So now I want to know how to assign the IP from the DHCP server on the network.

Comment: Your responses to comments belong in your question, not the comments. Also, add the output (text not a picture) of ifconfig to your question.